# Could not find or load main class osx terminal

Tags: java, macos, terminal, classpath

None of the answers to this common question solve my problem.

I have a file directory tree like such

```
root
 |
 +--> com
        |
        +--> Game.java
        +--> Window.java
```

I compiled `Game.java` and `Window.java` sucesffully and the resulting tree is like so

```
root
 |
 +--> com
        |
        +--> Game.java
        +--> Game.class
        +--> Window.java
        +--> Window.class
```

I changed directory back to root and ran the following command from the osx terminal

> java com.Game

and the I received the following error

> Could not find or load main class

I'm not sure why, here are my classes

`Game.java`

```
package com;

import java.awt.*;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    private static final long mSerialVersionUid = -240870510533527854L;

    public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;

    public Game(){

        new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Let's build a game!", this);
    }

    public synchronized void start(){

    }

    @Override
    public void run(){

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){


    }
}
```

`Window.java`

```
package com;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class Window extends Canvas {

    public Window(int width, int height, String title, Game game){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        game.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem was that a class path must be at least a two level deep domain name. I have only a domain name that is only one level deep.

Comment: @Stephen C This is not a duplicate, I am not asking what the error means, I am asking how to solve it, there are multiple solutions to this error.

Comment: The linked answers explain how to solve it.  But you need to read them, and work out which of the solutions apply to your particular version of the problem.  But seriously, you can't expect people to provide a fresh answer for your Question, just because you can't find one of the many previous answers.   This stuff is not rocket science ... but you do need to **understand** it ... not just copy/paste an solution.   If you understand it, then you can solve it.

Comment: Thank you for your concern, but none of the solutions worked for me. Adding an additional path to the class path solved my problem. When I said domain name, I confused the practice of using a domain name to create a class path with the actual nomenclature of the class path. Yes, I get it, a domain name is not a class path.

Comment: Did you read this?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/18093929/139985  - specifically *"Reason #2 - the application's classpath is incorrectly specified"*.  And the material that it links to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work as expected — I ran your code on **macOS 10.12.4** and it worked just fine ;)

You might have the `CLASSPATH` *environment variable* — without the current directory! — defined in your shell. If this is the case, try this instead:

```
java -cp . com.Game
```

By the way, to actually show the window you defined, create a `Game` object in your `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Game(); 
}
```

Comment: `java -cp . com.Game` results in the same error message

Comment: The problem was that a class path must be at least a two level deep domain name. I have only a domain name that is only one level deep.

Comment: *"The problem was that a class path must be at least a two level deep domain name. I have only a domain name that is only one level deep."* - I am afraid that that is nonsense.  The classpath is a series of pathnames, not domain names.  Please READ the Q&A the linked to ... and to the linked articles that explain what the classpath is.